# What's the best way to implement Change in email in SSO

Tags: single-sign-on

I have a centralized Identity provider that manages user's authentication across the board.

Other apps use SSO to integrate with identity server. ( They maps local user with SSO user using "email" )

I have to deal with a scenario where user changes their email in identity provider. ( Now this changes need to be propagated in all systems). I was given two ways to implement this.

1. Identity Server exposes webhooks that other apps can subscribe to when there's a change in email as it happens.
2. Use unique user_id to map local users to SSO (This way change in email won't affect authentication)

How good is #2 approach ? Considering that I may have to update several tables when an email is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually implement both approaches, they are not mutually exclusive:

- Exposing webhooks for applications to subscribe to user profile updates can let them always have the latest profile information without needing users to re-authenticate or having to poll the identity provider for changes.
- Having a unique, immutable user ID not tied to profile information such as email is generally a good practice. This lets you decouple identifiers from emails and lets you implement SSO without leaking user emails to applications that should not have them, which is especially important when performing SSO to untrusted third-party applications.

As a concrete example, Auth0 (disclaimer - I work for Auth0) implements the second approach for its built-in identity store, but could also implement the first approach to simplify the propagation of user profile modifications.

Comment: Thank you for reply, as both systems are internal so exposing email isn't an issue, infact using email as identifier simplifies the existing solution, however the problem is that I can only implement any one of them, so if i go with #2 without webhooks, I will have to perform the sync jobs passively at the time of login(when the user with changed email logs in) Unlike using webhooks.